# Trying to install dependencies

Tags: ros, rosdep, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install dependencies for [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#) following the instruction on the page:

```
rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg
```

But I keep getting the error saying:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource XXXXXXX
```

Basically, it is missing the resources that it is suppose to install, like octomap.

I've tried grabbing the missing resources manually, using rosws, but got stuck at octomap, where the error pops up even though octomap is already in the package path. So I decided to double back and try to investigate what I did or assumed wrong in the first place.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55701/trying-to-install-dependencies./) by [superawesomepandacat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3651/superawesomepandacat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume that the missing resource is octomap_server? To install this you can run `sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-octomap-mapping`. Then try to run `rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg` again. All other dependencies should be installed afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) with karma: 143 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-14**:
Thats a bit odd, wouldn't the sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-octomap-mapping install all the rosdeps automatically for you anyway?

**Comment by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on 2013-03-14**:
No, the sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-octomap-mapping will install the dependencies of octo-mapping, not the dependencies of rgbdslam. So you still need to run rosdep install to install the other rgbdslam dependencies.

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-05-06**:
It still doesn't work. And the following problem occurs:
rgbdslam: Missing resource mapping_msgs
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/lili/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/home/lili/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros